# Invalid Hook Call into reusable react component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-component

I try to build some reusable react component.
I start with a simple component : a button like

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ButtonLike = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const addLike = () => {
        setCounter(counter => counter+1);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type='button' value='Like' onClick={addLike} /> {counter}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ButtonLike;
```

I run the build => npm run build with the following webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const config = require('./src/component/component.config.js');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    ButtonLike: './src/component/ButtonLike/ButtonLike.js',
  },
  output: {
    library: 'myLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Dossier de sortie pour les fichiers construits
    filename: (chunkData) => {
        const componentName = chunkData.chunk.name;
        const componentVersion = config.version[componentName];
        return `[name].${componentVersion}.js`;
      },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader', // Utilise babel-loader pour transpiler le code React
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], // Gère le chargement des fichiers CSS
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Then I Create a simple page using the component build

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root1"></div>   
    <div id="root2"></div>    
    <script  src="./ButtonLike.1.0.0.js" ></script>
    <script>        
        var myComponent = myLibrary.default;
        var myButtonLikeElement = React.createElement(myComponent);        
        const domContainer = document.getElementById('root1');
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
        root.render(myButtonLikeElement);                             
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following error

```
react.development.js:210 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:210
error @ react.development.js:184
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1593
useState @ react.development.js:1622
ButtonLike @ ButtonLike.js:8
be @ react-dom.production.min.js:18
gj @ react-dom.production.min.js:19
Ub @ react-dom.production.min.js:120
Qi @ react-dom.production.min.js:193
Nd @ react-dom.production.min.js:194
Qf @ react-dom.production.min.js:187
Oi @ react-dom.production.min.js:185
S @ react.production.min.js:17
U @ react.production.min.js:21
react-dom.production.min.js:121 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1623:21)
    at ButtonLike (ButtonLike.js:8:80)
    at of (react-dom.production.min.js:109:301)
    at Rk (react-dom.production.min.js:250:214)
    at Si (react-dom.production.min.js:195:185)
    at Pk (react-dom.production.min.js:195:116)
    at Nd (react-dom.production.min.js:194:492)
    at Qf (react-dom.production.min.js:187:439)
    at Oi (react-dom.production.min.js:185:400)
    at S (react.production.min.js:17:25)
```

I can not resolve this issue.

I checked my react version and it is 18.2.0

```
PS C:\APPLIS\ACE\poc-prise-rdv> npm ls react
poc-prise-rdv@0.1.0 C:\APPLIS\ACE\poc-prise-rdv
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-hook-form@7.46.2
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.16.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├── react@18.2.0
└─┬ semantic-ui-react@2.1.4
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-event-listener@0.63.1
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-ref@0.63.1
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @semantic-ui-react/event-stack@3.1.3
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ react-popper@2.3.0
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  └── react@18.2.0 deduped

PS C:\APPLIS\ACE\poc-prise-rdv> npm ls react-dom
poc-prise-rdv@0.1.0 C:\APPLIS\ACE\poc-prise-rdv
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.16.0
│ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
└─┬ semantic-ui-react@2.1.4
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-event-listener@0.63.1
  │ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-ref@0.63.1
  │ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @semantic-ui-react/event-stack@3.1.3
  │ └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
  ├── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped
  └─┬ react-popper@2.3.0
    └── react-dom@18.2.0 deduped

PS C:\APPLIS\ACE\poc-prise-rdv>
```

I modify the webpack.config.js to remove react and react-dom

```
    const path = require('path');
const config = require('./src/component/component.config.js');


module.exports = {
  externals: {
    'react': 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom'
  },
  entry: {
    main: './src/App.js',  
    CreateRDV: './src/component/CreateRDV/CreateRDV.js',
    ButtonLike: './src/component/ButtonLike/ButtonLike.js',
  },
  output: {
    library: 'sfr',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Dossier de sortie pour les fichiers construits
    filename: (chunkData) => {
        const componentName = chunkData.chunk.name;
        const componentVersion = config.version[componentName];
        return `[name].${componentVersion}.js`;
      },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader', // Utilise babel-loader pour transpiler le code React
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], // Gère le chargement des fichiers CSS
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Now i have the following error

```
react-dom.production.min.js:121 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useState')
    at ButtonLike (ButtonLike.js:11:71)
    at of (react-dom.production.min.js:109:301)
    at Rk (react-dom.production.min.js:250:214)
    at Si (react-dom.production.min.js:195:185)
    at Pk (react-dom.production.min.js:195:116)
    at Nd (react-dom.production.min.js:194:492)
    at Qf (react-dom.production.min.js:187:439)
    at Oi (react-dom.production.min.js:185:400)
    at S (react.production.min.js:17:25)
    at MessagePort.U (react.production.min.js:21:60)
```

Comment: Nowhere are you calling `ReactDOM.createRoot`

Comment: May not be related to your issue, but one improvement for your addLike() would be to use `setCounter(counter => counter+1);` instead of `setCounter(counter+1);` as you need to update counter based on its previous value, so former should be helpful due to async nature of setCounter setter

Comment: It should be something like `root.render(React.createElement(myButtonLikeElement, {}, null))`